# \StoreResolverInterface->getCurrentStoreId() taking huge amount of time to resolve current store ID in StoreManager.php

Tags: multistore, performance, core, magento2.3.4

Running Magento 2.3.4 and encountering an issue with Magento core code.

For the past couple of days I've been battling terrible performance on my site, especially when serving uncached content via `pub/static`.

Investigating this by enabling Magento's profiler, I noticed that the `store.resolve` event was **taking upwards of 12 seconds to process when fetching a single JavaScript file via `pub/static`**:

[image]

Looking at the code, this event is located in the `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager` class:

```
    public function getStore($storeId = null)
    {
        if (!isset($storeId) || '' === $storeId || $storeId === true) {
            if (null === $this->currentStoreId) {
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('store.resolve');
                $this->currentStoreId = $this->storeResolver->getCurrentStoreId();
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('store.resolve');
            }
            $storeId = $this->currentStoreId;
        }
        if ($storeId instanceof \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface) {
            return $storeId;
        }

        $store = is_numeric($storeId)
            ? $this->storeRepository->getById($storeId)
            : $this->storeRepository->get($storeId);

        return $store;
    }
```

`storeResolver` is an instance of `Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface`, the direct usage of which I notice has been [deprecated](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/) by Magento, maybe because of performance issues.

Following the code further, it looks like Magento tries to determine the current store code from the current HTTP request, eventually ending up in `Magento\Store\App\Request\StorePathInfoValidator->getValidStoreCode()`.

However I haven't been able to find out why the performance is so poor.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?